# How to transform the PDE?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

I am doing the following problem:

*Transform the equation*
$$y\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right) - x \left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} \right) = (y-x)z$$

*by introuducing new independent variables:*

$$u = x^2 + y^2, v = \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y}$$

*and a new function:*

$$w = \ln(z) - (x + y)$$

I did everything as it is in the example I have (system of first order diferentials) and I got to this equation as the new one:

$$\left(\frac{xz}{y^2}- \frac{yz}{x^2}\right) \frac{\partial w}{\partial v} = 0$$

The solutions say this is the result:  $\frac{\partial w}{\partial v} = 0$

I checked multiple times what I've done and I cannot find a mistake. Am I allowed to divide by the term in the braces and treat it as a constant that's different from 0? If I can, why? It doesn't make sense to me. If we try to write it in terms of v and w, we cannot divide it at all.

How to do this properly and is there another way at approaching it?

Comment: I tried separation of variables and arrived at $\frac{dF}{dx}\frac{1}{F(x)}=\frac{dG}{dy}\frac{1}{G(y)}=1$

Comment: which would mean $z=e^{y+z}$ which is too restrictive

Comment: How did you arive at that solution? What is F and what is G?

Comment: i separated $z(x,y)=F(x)G(y)$

Comment: I understand, but it stills doesn't answer my question. Your solution is completely different from what I am required to get.

Comment: So in your final equation $$\left(\frac{xz}{y^2}- \frac{yz}{x^2}\right) \frac{\partial w}{\partial v} = 0$$ the RHS being zero means that the product of the factors on LHS must always be zero.  Since the first factor varies with x, y and z, the second factor must always equal zero.

Comment: Maybe I'm thinking boundaries but what if there is a point where the first term is equal to zero?

Comment: Sure ... the first factor will be zero when $x^3=y^3$ or when $z=0$ and it'd be possible, I suppose, that at those locations the second factor could be allowed to be non-zero but that seems overly constrictive and discontinuous.

Answer (score 0):

Making

$$
z(x,y) = e^{x+y}e^{w(x,y)}
$$

and proceeding with the change of variables, after some symbolic effort we get at

$$
\frac{v \sqrt{u v^2+1} \left(\sqrt{u v^2+1}+1\right) \sqrt{\frac{u v^2-2 \left(\sqrt{u v^2+1}+1\right)}{v^2}} \exp
   \left(w(u,v)+\frac{u v^2+\sqrt{u v^2+1}+1}{v \sqrt{u v^2+1}}\right)\frac{\partial w}{\partial v}(u,v)}{u v^2+2 \sqrt{u v^2+1}+2}=0\Rightarrow \frac{\partial w}{\partial v}(u,v)=0
$$

Comment: That seems like a lot of symbolic effort..